# Node Version Manager runs very slow on M1 Macbook Air

Tags: node.js, nvm, apple-m1

I am currently finding that running Node Version Manager on my M1 Macbook (using zsh console), it is running node commands very slowly.

An npm install can take 30+ minutes to complete.
However, if I don't use NVM and decide to install the same version of node directly, the commands runs much faster as expected (2 minutes for an npm install).

I have tried using different versions of node with NVM and the commands still run slow.
I have also tried to run terminal using Rosetta and they still take forever to run.

Looking around I have seen people complain about NVM starting slowly but mine loads almost instantly, its just commands running that takes a long time.

Is this just an M1 chip issue or have I possibly done something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, installing the `node` version using the 64-bit X86 architecture fixed the issue.

Here is the instruction(look at section: Macs with M1 chip):
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#macos-troubleshooting

Comment: this saved me. specifically running this `arch -x86_64 zsh` then re-running the `nvm instal...` command

Comment: Same. I tried a few other things but this has been the only thing that's made a huge difference. After reinstalling `node` under Rosetta things run much faster both inside _and_ outside of Rosetta (i.e., when `arch` returns `arm64`).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I found that changing the version of node helped immensely.

I was using node 12 at the time of the question and since upgrading to node 15 using NVM, I found that it ran much quicker and was actually usable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).