# create-react-app my-app takes 2 - 2.5 hours? Any idea why?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

My machine is not weak by any means. 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16gb ram, 256 SDD, Radeon Pro 555 2 gb. I read in other threads that it should take 2 - 3 minutes. Here’s the output I’m getting. Clearly, something looks off, but I don't know how to interpret it. It keeps spitting out similar things for the entire duraction. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have 300 MBPS. It's not a wifi thing. Node version is 14.17.3 and npm is version 7.24.1.

```
MBP:10-Hour-Projects macbook$ create-react-app vidly

Creating a new React app in /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Main Drive/Javascript/10-Hour-Projects/vidly.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning react-scripts > @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin > native-url > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > sockjs > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > webpack-log > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > babel-jest > @jest/transform > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
warning react-scripts > postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-functional-notation > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
warning react-scripts > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[#############----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 3826/37058
```

Comment: Check your internet connection speed

Comment: I have 300 MBPS.

Comment: [Are node and npm up-to-date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41524903/1218980)

Comment: Node version is 14.17.3. And npm verion is 7.24.1. Not the latest per say, but I highly doubt that that is the issue here.

Comment: [Maybe an m1 issue with node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66851705/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron, my mac is actually intel-powered, not M1!

Comment: I don't believe we can tell exactly what's the issue from the info in the question, though I can tell you it's unusually long, that's for sure.

Comment: [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) suggests to use `npx create-react-app my-app` (or `yarn create react-app my-app`) to create a new app, to be sure to use the latest version.

Comment: I agree with Emile’s suggestion to use the latest CRA version. You should uninstall your globally installed CRA and then use one of the commands above.